# Getting the edit button to go where I need it too

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, edit

I've been trying to get the edit button, found on the FreshReleaseTableViewController, to simply take the user back to the AddFreshReleaseViewController.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Below is the edit button code I have:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)
    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}
```

Comment: Dumb question on my part, yet very important: you make it sound like `AddFreshReleaseViewController` "presents" `FreshReleaseViewController` - how? Give us something we can reproduce, and I'll bet we can help.

Comment: They don't present each other. In 'AddFreshReleaseViewController' you input information that shows up in a table cell in 'FreshReleaseViewController'. I just want to be able to have an edit button on the cells that takes you back to 'AddFreshReleaseViewController' in order to change the inputted info if need be.

Comment: I didn't quite ask if they "present each other". Under nearly 100% of the circumstances, one view controller has either (a) a segue to another controller - when using IB or a Storyboard, (b) *presents" modally a second view controller, **or** (c) uses child view controllers. I've never used `UIContextualAction` but I understand what it does. What I'm having a hard time conceptualizing from your question/comment is why an "Edit" button "takes you back" to something. It usually means "takes you to" something... a controller? a child controller? a view? I guess that's the detail I'm hung on.

Comment: Let me go into a quick overview of what I'm trying to create and it might help. I'm working on a new music release notification app where the user types in the artist, album and date. When a new release is added, it saves it to a list. Incase the information is typed in wrong or misspelled, I made an edit button. So it would take the user to where they originally inputed the data and have the information already in the fields. However, for the life of me I can't seem to get the edit button to do that.

Comment: One last time - and please, I've done no down-voting or voting to close. This edit button - I get that it would "take the user to where they originally input the data", but **HOW**? Let's talk technical. A view and/or/view controller **stack**. Normally, it should have - by your details - possibly "something" (maybe a Releases VC?) and then this FreshReleaseVC. Somehow the user gets a new release added. Maybe they even use AddFreshReleaseVC. And yes, they made a mistake and need to click the *edit* button that exists on FreshReleaseVC to correct things. Let me continue....

Comment: They DO NOT "go back in the stack from "Something" >> FreshRelease >> AddFreshRelease >> FreshRelease to... well, "Something". Push/Pop. If you pushed AddFreshRelease from FreshRelease, you pop back to FreshRelease. You don't "magically" go from FreshRelease *back* to AddFreshRelease. Maybe it's me missing something. But right now I'm wondering if you aren't recognizing how VC stacks should work.